# Simple remote process object interaction in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I'm sure there has to be an easy way to do this, maybe I'm making more work for myself than I need to.  I'm trying to set up cross system communications in a way that I can have bi-directional communication between objects, I imagine it would be something like this.

```
public interface ISharedResource

public class SharedResourceHost : ISharedResource  //<- slave process

SharedResourceHost resource = new SharedResourceHost("http://192.168.1.102/HostedResources/Process1");

resource.Invoke("SomeMethod");
```

is there anything like this? I don't wanna have to pull teeth setting up web services etc but if I have to I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check WCF. It is far too big to explain here but this article should give you some pointers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb907581.aspx

WCF allows you to set up interfaces in which two objects can communicate using a protocol of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You're definitely re-inventing the wheel here.  Look at the [`System.Runtime.Remoting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.aspx) namespace.  I'd link in a tutorial, but I'd just have to check [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+remoting) and you can evaluate what will make more sense for you better than I.

Comment: is remoting the EASY answer to this?

Comment: Easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: *laughs* is WCF an easier solution? I hear it's better but in my 'experimentation' I've been mostly swearing at the configuration due to my complete lack of ITS background.

Comment: WCF essentially replaces System.Net.Remoting in .NET 3.0 (along with much other networking/web-related stuff and adding new functionality). If you're just doing simple remoting, WCF should be fairly straightforward (perhaps marginally harder), but it's the right way to go really.

Comment: It'd be nice if I just had an example of a cross system "ping/pong" service. where if application A sends a ping application B returns pong, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd want either [Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.80).aspx) or [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx).  However in both instances you're going to need to make sure you have the correct ports open.  I don't see how setting up [Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx) would be difficult, but I can only go off of your post.